# SSH authorization failed

Tags: git, ssh, hexo

I wanted to build a blog by hexo on a remote server, it works well to connect it by ssh as root, and I had add a git user with public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

```
-rw------- 1 git git 417 3月  26 23:17 authorized_keys
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 3月  26 23:17 .ssh
```

But it failed when I tried to connect the server by ssh as git user.
The debug info are as below. Could anyone help me to find out which part is wrong?

```
    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/merci/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
    debug1: Authenticating to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'git'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256  SHA256:WtiBAvKVU22BbHmoyYAuil40oQVFVFQIkawWk0OtrcA
    debug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xxx.x' xxis known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/merci/.ssh/known_hosts:9
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:DHpAEIuYidbjTQWkij0GNroO+mdwPWq128YLQu0lk5I
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_rsa RSA  SHA256:DHpAEIuYidbjTQWkij0GNroO+mdwPWq128YLQu0lk5I
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/merci/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: please provide the comand line you used to connect. Also, show the permissions on your .ssh/authorized_keys file for the git user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all rename the file in `authorized_keys`
and then set right permissions to ssh folder and authorized_keys file.

```sh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: sorry, it's authorized_keys, and i've done the chmod before